# Has a holographic library been found in tunnels under the Bucegi mountains?

Tags: aliens, archeology

There have been some extraordinary claims about a set of tunnels under the [Bucegi mountains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucegi_Mountains) in Romania.

*[The Niburu Sunset](https://thenibirusunset.wordpress.com/2015/04/25/tunnels-in-bucegi-mountains-shows-our-true-history/)* blog has an interesting collection of videos on the topic.

> The BUCEGI MOUNTAINS have a huge SPHINX under which are tunnels and chambers. There is a huge main chamber which holds a protective energy system and which contains a HOLOGRAPHIC LIBRARY (HOLOGRAPHIC CONTROL PANELS) of the EARTH’S past HISTORY as well as instructions on how to construct and mix human and animal DNA and the expected results of the mixtures.

Can we verify if any of these claimed findings?

Comment: Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence. If this were true it would be very easy to prove. The onus of proof is on the claimants. But they also claim that you can only see the artefacts *if the alien wants you to see them*. Presumably this is a getout clause to avoid having any actual, objective proof. I think we can ignore any claim with that sort of caveat.

Answer (score 3):

Evidence: [The Sphinx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphinx_(Romania)) is a natural rock formation in the Bucegi Natural Park located  at an altitude of 2,216 metres (7,270 ft) which is in the Bucegi Mountains of Romania. It is also true that the area contains a variety of caves and caverns.

Claim explanation: The claim of Holographic library (Holographic control panels) of the Earth's past history under the sphinx [is based on](http://www.topsecretwriters.com/2012/12/is-there-any-truth-behind-the-bucegi-mountain-discovery/) time travel science fiction from a book called [Transylvanian Sunrise](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0967816254) by Peter Moon and [Radu Cinamar](https://translate.google.co.in/translate?hl=en&sl=ro&u=https://ro.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radu_Cinamar&prev=search). Peter Moon further [claims](http://www.digitalmontauk.com/?p=318) that the chamber beneath the sphinx is only accessible if an alien being wants you to access it.

> In ancient times, the Golden Thrones Chamber (described in The Secret Parchment) was used by the high priests. During the time of Burebista, one of the most famous kings of Dacia, a man named Deceneus was the high priest. He also served the equally famous Decebal who hid a legendary treasure from the Romans. It was Deceneus who made ​​the connection with Zalmoxis in another reality. There are other portals to the other reality that exist not far from Sarmizegetusa and they all lead to the Valley of the Golden Thrones. The Golden Thrones Chamber is immune from electronic devices, including alien devices, because it exists in the consciousness of a being that uses its intention to open portals to it. **It is only accessible if that being wants you to access it.**

The following is taken from the abstract of the Amazon paperback version of the book.

> A mysterious scientist by the name of David Anderson made an eventful trip to Romania in 1999. Dr. Anderson, who is credited by the U.S. government as having developed advanced time-warp field technology, established diplomatic connections on this trip to Romania where he also set up an advanced research facility dedicated to studying the mathematics of time travel. Upon his return to the United States, Dr. Anderson visited Preston Nichols and Peter Moon, internationally known authors of “The Montauk Project: Experiments in Time,” and introduced himself.
>
> Dr. Anderson’s continued journeys to Romania eventually resulted in connecting Peter Moon with a Romanian publisher and Radu Cinamar, a member of the Romanian Intelligence Service’s occult department. The purpose of this collaboration has to do with what is arguably the most significant archaeological discovery in the history of Mankind: a mysterious holographic hall of records that utilizes technology far beyond the concepts of modern science. Transylvanian Sunrise is the story of this mysterious discovery and the political intrigue surrounding it, all capably told by Radu Cinamar.

However certain issues are noted with the claim of the characters mentioned in the fictitious story.

1. Radu Cinamar has been previously claimed to have risen to prominence for his role in exposing the most remarkable archaeological discovery in the history of Mankind: a secret chamber beneath the Romanian Sphinx containing holographic records of Earth’s history, bio-resonance imaging technology, and three mysterious tunnels leading to the deepest secrets of the Inner Earth per the book [Transylvanian Moonrise: A Secret Initiation in the Mysterious Land of the Gods](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0967816289). However, Radu Cinamar is not noted in Wikipedia's [list of notable archaeologists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_archaeologists) even though he has claimed to have exposed the most remarkable archaeological discovery.

   Radu Cinamar is also claimed to be a member of the Romanian Intelligence Service’s occult department. However when one searches for the occult [department](http://www.sri.ro/?language=en&cauta=occult&submit=) of the Romanian Intelligence Service or Radu [Cinamar](http://www.sri.ro/?language=en&cauta=Radu+Cinamar&submit=) in the claim, it did not return any results.
2. The mysterious profile of Dr David Lewis [Anderson](http://peswiki.com/index.php/Directory:Anderson_Institute%27s_Time_Control_Technology) has been already analyzed by [other](http://www.skepticforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=17237) skeptics in [2010](http://old.timetravelinstitute.com/threads/dr-david-andersons-work-on-time-travel.6303/), [2011](http://www.internationalskeptics.com/forums/showthread.php?t=221197) and [2012](http://historybizarremysterious.blogspot.in/2012/03/strange-case-of-dr-david-lewis-anderson.html). The information that he was employed by the USAAF at Edwards air force base to do time research also cannot be proved by searching for the same in the Edwards air force [website](http://search.af.mil/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&affiliate=edwards&query=%22time+travel%22). His only awarded degree appears to be a BSEE from WV University in 1983. He also claimed in Coast to Coast AM, a North American late-night radio talk show  to have worked with Lijun Wang (though he calls him "Julian") at Princeton University but Wang worked at NRC Research and there's no record of Anderson ever being there. However, David Anderson has USPTO (United States Patents and Trademark Office) receipt for a time travel system application submitted in [2009](http://www.digitalmontauk.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/USPTO-Time-Reactor-EFS-ID-6627843-App-No-61286110.pdf).

Comment: Sorry, I found this answer confusing. It mixes claims and evidence. You describe the books as science fiction. I thought that answered the question, but now I realise that is your opinion, not the author's - to call it fiction is begging the question.

Comment: I am still unclear: Is Radu Cinamar a real person, a nom-de-plume, or entirely fictional? Ditto Dr David Lewis Anderson. What is Coast to Coast AM? What is an EPTO? Is the source of that (apparent) patent application trustworthy, or is it also fiction?

Comment: @Oddthinking-Radu Cinamar is a literary pseudonym of an unknown Romanian author. This pseudonym was included with real names such Pavel Coruţ in different books. Coast to Coast AM is a North American  late-night radio talk show that deals with a variety of topics relating to either the paranormal or conspiracy theories.

Comment: That helps, but we still don't know if the story is fiction or non-fiction. Is your argument "I failed to find these people when I tried to verify their resumes, therefore the stories they tell about themselves and the caves are fictitious."?

Comment: @Oddthinking Or maybe it is the fact that the book is talking about time warp field technology might make it fiction?

Comment: @Lyrion: That is [begging the question](http://www.nizkor.org/features/fallacies/begging-the-question.html). The OP has found an extraordinary claim, which ultimately derives from a book, and is asking if it is true. We need to find the evidence that supports or refutes the claim, not just assume it is false because it is extraordinary. (Of course, my default position as a skeptic is to provisionally reject the claim until strong evidence is found, but that is a different issue.)

Comment: @Oddthinking-There is no record of discovery by Radu Cinamar in any noted archaeology site about the chamber beneath the sphinx in Bucegi Mountains, Romania and the claims by Peter Moon that the chamber is only accessible if that being wants you to access it is also not a known archaeological method for excavation. The resume verification was not done by me but by several other skeptic sites and also the absence of a department of occult in Romanian Intelligence add to the fictious part of the story. Transylvanian Sunrise is the only book which is the reference for this remarkable fiction!